# Windows 10 with ATT Gigabit but I can't get over 200 mpbs, same cable gets 900 mbps on windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-10, gigabit-ethernet

I have a Windows 10 PC with a wired internet connection and gigabit service from AT&T. If I do any speed tests, the maximum speed I can attain is 200 mbps. If I take the same exact Cat 6 cable from the back of my computer and plug it into my Windows 7 laptop, I get 900 mbps.

I thought maybe this meant that I had a bad network card,, so I replaced it with a Rosewill gigabit PCIe LAN card that is confirmed to work with Win 10, same speed.

I have tried the following:

- Changed Cables
- Changed Ports on the modem
- Updated drivers
- Disabled Autotuning
- Changed Speed and Duplex from Auto to 1 Gbps full duplex

I am running:

- Windows 10
- Rosewill RC-411 network card
- Asus M5A99Z EVO motherboard
- 16 GB RAM
- 6 core 3.3 GHz AMD FX-6100 processor

I can't find anything that is throttling it program-wise either. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.